# How do I update multiple records in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have millions of records in a table and I need to update particular records which have wrong values. How do I do it?

Example:

```
Si Item_Id
1  T21547856
2  T45200254
3  T54785000
```

Need to update like:

```
T21547856 = CS2541
T54785000 = CS5475
```

This is just an example. I have millions of records and need to update more than half a million.

Comment: @Deepak Just so you know, having no question mark on "How to do multiple record updation in oracle" was in fact correct, so your edit did not fix the grammar, but rather broke it. See [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20730/3976) on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for more info.

Comment: Do see this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292243/please-dont-just-approve-trivial-suggested-edits-rather-improve-the-edit-per-th

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be:

Create an index on item_id, then just do the updates. `update table set item_id = 'CS2541' where itme_id = 'T21547856'`

This works only item_ids are unique in your table.

After this, you may drop the index if you don't need it.

A second approach would be to create another table, B,  with values to be updated:

```
si item_id
1 CS2541
3 CS5475
```

Then do a `merge`:

```
merge into your_table a
using b
on a.si=b.si
when matched then update set a.item_id=b.item_id;
```

Comment: The second approach sounds like a winner. If so, no need for an index.